# Random forest final stage: Consider the training dataset or the entire dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, scikit-learn

I trained and tuned a random forest classifier using cross validation and train-test split, as in 70% training dataset (which is then cross validated 5 splits, 6 times) and 30% test dataset. With the CV I managed to get the best hyper-parameters and with the test dataset I obtained the performance score. This [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/train-final-machine-learning-model/) suggests that after everything is ready, one should then refit/retrain the model with the same configuration as before but on the entire dataset now (not the training dataset anymore).

However, I wonder if this wouldn't mess with the hyper-parameters that were defined before specifically for the training data. Also, I wonder if this would not somehow change the nature of the model (as it would most likely start getting 100% accuracy in the entire dataset). This is particularly important for me because I need to use the model on another similar dataset to predict synthetic values. How do you guys usually proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of your test set is to help you **objectively evaluate** your model's performance on unseen data. If you selected your hyperparameters with CV (on the training set) and you have only run the test set once in the end for a final evaluation, you can consider it to depict your model's performance.

If you are OK with this performance, you can retrain your model on the whole data and expect it to perform **at least on par** to what it did on the test set (assuming that the new unseen data follows the same distribution as your training/test sets).

Your model's accuracy on the (new) training set doesn't tell you anything. The performance you should look at is that which your model had, when it was objectively evaluated.

Likewise you should use the **same hyperparameters** as the previous step because they were the ones that achieved the performance you wanted. Changing them after merging the dataset could result in deteriorating the actual model's performance (though you would't know, because now there is no way of objectively evaluating your model). One thing also to note is that the addition of 30% more data shouldn't affect their selection by much.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's precisely the type of confirmation I was looking for. My dataset is not very large, therefore every bit of extra data will be welcome in the training of the model.

Comment: One more question if I may: When demonstrating the final performance of the model, I learned that (and you kind of confirmed in your answer) that we should always present the score on the (untouched) test data. Yet, I've come across a researcher saying that the scores on validation test with CV are more robust and less sensitive to the position of the test set. Does this make sense? Should I think of a second level of cross validation is this case to test the performance on multiple untouched test sets? Thank you.

Comment: This is a difficult question to ask. CV is in general as a technique more robust than a test-set. However in our case we use the CV for hyperparameter tuning, which might cause our model to overfit on the validation sets (CV is good though at preventing this). For this reason we consider the test set to be more robust than the k validation sets of the CV, that have also been used for tuning! This all assumes that the test set is used only once, in the end and did not in any way affect your selection of model/hyperparameters!

Comment: Another thing to note is that you can use both CV for tuning and final evaluation if you want to be as robust as you can be (with a sacrifice in computational complexity). This is called [nested cross-validation](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/03/a-step-by-step-guide-to-nested-cross-validation/)

Comment: That's more than I could have hoped for. I'll check the nested cross-validation. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! :D